# Error in Production :CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SendEscalationMail: execution of BeforeUpdate

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, case-object

I have a requirement where i need to create a VF page ,Apex controller and test class.If I run the test class  on my developer console .I get no errors and the outcome of the test is 100% successfully tested.

When I deploy using change set from my sandbox to production and I get this error message in production while validating:

```
 MassCaseCloseTest.TestMassCaseClose(),

Details: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 5003800000iVvKuAAK; 

first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SendEscalationMail: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.SendEscalationMail: line 358, column 1: [] 

Class.MassCaseClose.save: line 26, column 1 Class.MassCaseCloseTest.TestMassCaseClose: line 27, column 1
```

Controller :

```
public with sharing class MassCaseClose {

      public Case objCase {get;set;} 
      private List<Case> lstCase; 
      public MassCaseClose() 
      { 
           objCase = new Case(); 
           lstCase = new List<Case>(); 
           String strRecordIds = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ids');
            set<Id> setCaseIds = new set<Id>();
            for(String strid : strRecordIds.split(','))
            {
                setCaseIds.add(id.valueof(strid.trim()));
            }
            lstCase = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN: setCaseIds];
     } 
     public PageReference save() 
   { 
      for(Case objCaseRecord: lstCase) 
    { 
      objCaseRecord.Status = objCase.Status; 
      objCaseRecord.Closer_Comment__c=objCase.Closer_Comment__c;
       } 
      update lstCase; 
      return new pagereference('/500'); 

   } 
     public PageReference cancel() 
    { 
      return new pagereference('/500'); 
  } 

}
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest
public class MassCaseCloseTest{
    public static TestMethod void TestMassCaseClose(){

       Account a = new Account();
        a.Name ='TestAccount';        
        insert a;

        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.FirstName ='Test';
        c.LastName ='Contact';
        insert c;

        Case cas = new Case();
        cas.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';
        insert cas; 
        cas.Status='Closed';
        update case;  

        Test.startTest();
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('ids',cas.id);
        MassCaseClose objCase = new MassCaseClose ();
        /*objCase.Status = 'Closed';
        objCase.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';*/
        objCase.save();
        Test.stopTest();
    }   
     public static TestMethod void TestMassCaseClose1(){

       Account a = new Account();
        a.Name ='TestAccount';        
        insert a;

        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.FirstName ='Test';
        c.LastName ='Contact';
        insert c;

        Case cas = new Case();
        cas.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';
        insert cas; 
        cas.Status='Closed';
        update case;  

        Test.startTest();
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('ids',cas.id);
        MassCaseClose objCase = new MassCaseClose ();
        /*objCase.Status = 'Closed';
        objCase.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';*/
        objCase.Cancel();
        Test.stopTest();
    }   
   }
```

Part of Trigger :

```
if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore ){
            System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
           // List<String> queueNameList = new List<String>({'Triage','RDBA','Support','RDBA - ACM',});

            List<Group> groupList = [Select Id,Name From Group where Type = 'Queue' And (Name = 'Triage' OR Name = 'RDBA' Or Name = 'Support')]; 
            //SObjectType caseType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Case');
           // Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = caseType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

            Profile prof = [Select Id,Name from Profile where id =: UserInfo.getProfileId()];

            Set<Id> userIdSet = new Set<ID>();
            for(Case newCase: Trigger.new){
                String ownerIdString = newCase.OwnerId;
                if(ownerIdString.startswith('005')){
                    userIdSet.add(newCase.OwnerId);
                    //System.debug('newCase.OwnerId = '+newCase.OwnerId);
                }
            }

            System.debug('User Id Set = '+userIdSet);
            Map<Id,User> userMap;
            if(!userIdSet.isEmpty()){
                userMap = new Map<Id,User>([Select Id,Name,Queue__c From user where id In : userIdSet]);
                 //System.debug('userMap  = '+ userMap );
            }
            Map<Id,Group> groupMap = new Map<Id,Group>(groupList);


            Map<Id,Case> oldCaseMap = Trigger.oldMap;
            Map<Id,Case> newCaseMap = Trigger.newMap;

            List<Case_Comment__c> caseCommentList = new List<Case_Comment__c>();
            for(Id caseId : newCaseMap.keyset()){
               Case newCase = newCaseMap.get(caseId);
               Case oldCase = oldCaseMap.get(caseId);
               if(newCase.RecordTypeID == recTypeList[0].id || newCase.RecordTypeID == recTypeList[1].id || newCase.RecordTypeID == recTypeList[2].id || newCase.RecordTypeID == recTypeList[3].id || newCase.RecordTypeID == recTypeList[4].id || newCase.RecordTypeID == recTypeList[5].id){
                   if(newCase != null && oldCase != null){
                        if(newCase.Case_Comment_Time__c == null ){
                            newCase.Case_Comment_Status__c = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            if(newCase.Case_Comment_Time__c == oldCase.Case_Comment_Time__c){
                                newCase.Case_Comment_Status__c = true;
                            }
                            else{
                                newCase.Case_Comment_Status__c = false;
                            }
                        }
                        **if(!newCase.Status.equals(oldCase.Status)){**
                            Case_Escalation_Days__c caseEscalationDays = caseEscalationDaysMap.get(newCase.Status.trim().toLowerCase());
```

The Error message where i get is for the Trigger  is :

**if(!newCase.Status.equals(oldCase.Status)){**

I shall appreciate your help.

Comment: please share you trigger code `SendEscalationMail`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ create your trigger here and provide a link so other can review

Comment: @Tushar Sharma:Thanks for your reply.Based on business requirement the trigger has been written by sumone else...but if i make any changes it will get effected.So do i have an alternate to change the code of my requirement .Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: check case status default picklist value for both sandbox and production. In production default value is not set, what i believe.

Comment: @Ratan:In sandbox and production the Status field has a default value "NEW"

Comment: have you tried with below options?

Comment: @Ratan:I tried the case inserting with the status open and updating as close.i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!newCase.Status.equals(oldCase.Status))
```

In this case Your old case Status is null thats why you are getting this error. Please give any valid status to case when you insert the record. it will solve your problem.

Another thing is in your SB you have some default value for case thats why your code is working but in production you don't have any default value so it is giving error. Please check above conditions and your problem will be solved.